# How do I change the owner of a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions

When I accidentally click on the Database Diagrams tab, I get one of the following errors:

> Database diagram support objects
>   cannot be installed because this
>   database does not have a valid owner.
>   To continue, first use the Files page
>   of the Database Properties dialog box
>   or the ALTER AUTHORIZATION statement
>   to set the database owner to a valid
>   login, then add the database diagram
>   support objects.

--- or ---

> The database does not have one or more
>   of the support objects required to use
>   database diagramming. Do you wish to
>   create them?

What's the syntax for changing the owner of this database to 'sa'?

Comment: I don't understand why you think that this has anything to do with the owner? It just wants to know if it should create the objects to make diagrams possible.

Comment: If I change the owner, then I don't get prompted to create the objects. I'm not sure if they are automatically created afterwards.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

to change the object owner try the following

```
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
```

that however is not your problem, to see diagrams the Da Vinci Tools objects have to be created (you will see tables and procs that start with dt_) after that

Comment: As per BOL: This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Use ALTER AUTHORIZATION instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Sorry for necropost and/or if this is too obvious: What prevents any good old user from executing this command and making themselves the sa?

Comment: @gary - only users with the "TAKE OWNERSHIP" on the target database and either "IMPERSONATE" on their login if they have an existing user in the DB, or "CONTROL SERVER". See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-changedbowner-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 108):

To change database owner:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::YourDatabaseName TO sa
```

As of SQL Server 2014 you can still use `sp_changedbowner` as well, even though Microsoft promised to remove it in the "future" version after SQL Server 2012. They removed it from SQL Server 2014 BOL though.

Comment: @ilter - not sure I understood your comment. The question was 'What's the syntax for changing the owner of this database to 'sa'?'. I believe I answered this question. If you run this statement DB owner will be changed to sa. Moreover this is recommended syntax to use as the opposite to using older sp_changedbowner that will likely be retired eventually.

Comment: I've been at this for 2 days going down every single path for `Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\user', error code 0x5. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15404)`. I never went this route because my db owner was ***already*** sa.

Comment: After I resolved every single SQL event log error to no avail and removed all traces of said user, I decided that somehow, someway, the user it was barking about ***had*** to be orphaned within the depths of SQL somewhere. Red Gate's SQL Search revelead 0 entries for the user. I was relegated to doing something that was completely counter-intuitive. I ran this command ... and the error was no more; diagrams could be created. ***Take away is this:*** Even if you already have sa as the owner, ***RUN THIS COMMAND*** and save yourself the headache!

Answer (score 4):

This is a prompt to create a bunch of object, such as sp_help_diagram (?), that do not exist.

This should have nothing to do with the owner of the db.

Comment: Can you explain why that I am no longer prompted for this after I change the owner? Are the objects automatically created or does SQL Server just stop asking me because my account is no longer the owner?

Comment: In this case, the DB was owned by login that had been dropped. I'm not sure why because "sa" owns all our databases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to change the owner on ALL DBS (excluding System)

```
EXEC sp_msforeachdb'
USE [?]
IF ''?'' <> ''master'' AND ''?'' <> ''model'' AND ''?'' <> ''msdb'' AND ''?'' <> ''tempdb''
BEGIN
 exec sp_changedbowner ''sa''
END
'
```

Comment: Dont use sp_msforeachdb unless you like missing databases occasionally, this is a documented issue.